# fifth parameter is not displaying in the cart.index page

Tags: laravel

I'm sending five parameter to add to cart function,Here is the code

```
<form action="{{route('cart.store')}}" method="post">                          {{ csrf_field() }}
                              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$product->id}}">
                              <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{{$product->name}}">
                              <input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{$product->price}}">
                              <input type="hidden" name="destination" value="{{$product->destination}}">
                               value=""> 

                      <button type="submit">click me</button>
                           </form>
```

The code of **cartController** is

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
         Cart::add($request->id, $request->name, 1 , $request->price , ['destination' => $request->destination]);
              return redirect()->route('cart.index')->with('success_message','Item was added to your cart');
    } // i have also tried 
Cart::add(array('id' => $request->id, 'name' => $request->name, 'qty' => 1, 
    'price' => $request->price, 'destination' => $request->destination));
```

And the code for cart.index is

```
 <tbody>
                             @foreach(Cart::content() as $row)
                        <tr>
                          <td><a href="#"><img src="img/detailsquare.jpg" alt="White Blouse Armani" class="img-fluid"></a></td>
                          <td><a href="#">{{$row->id}}</a></td>
                          <td><a href="#">{{$row->name}}</a></td>
                          <td>{{$row->qty}}</td>
                          <td>{{$row->price}}</td>
                           <td>{{$row->destination}}</td>
                          <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td>
                        </tr>
                         @endforeach
                      </tbody>
```

This is not giving me any error and display the product id,name,quantity,price but did not displays the destination. Anyone have a solution

Comment: For some fast debugging, `$product->destination ?? 'product destination is empty'` and `$request->get('destination', 'request destination is empty')`.

Comment: I want to show some extra details about the product. That why used this destination, but this is giving me empty result as you are saying, how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Most likely destination is not being stored when the product is being created. Please check on db to be sure.

Comment: Yes it is showing me empty destination field when i check using var_dump($request). You are right that destination is not being stored when product is created. do you have any solution of it ?

Comment: You need to properly store a destination when the product is created. You need to make a separate post with code related to creating a product.

Comment: How can i do this ? can you please guide ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra line after input type :

```
<form action="{{route('cart.store')}}" method="post">                          {{ csrf_field() }}
                              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$product->id}}">
                              <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{{$product->name}}">
                              <input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{$product->price}}">
                              <input type="hidden" name="destination[]" value="{{$product->destination}}">
                               /*value=""> */ // **remove this line**

                      <button type="submit">click me</button>
                           </form>
```

If not working then from **cartController** try `var_dump($request)` and see result.

Try this :

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
         Cart::add($request->id, $request->name, 1 , $request->price ,  $request->destination);
              return redirect()->route('cart.index')->with('success_message','Item was added to your cart');
    }
```

Also check your model and db.

Comment: Yes it is showing me empty destination field when i check using var_dump($request). destination is not being stored when product is created. do you have any solution of it ?

Comment: I it giving me error on that, argument 5 must be type of array. i'm using crisane laravel shopping cart

Comment: `name="destination[]" ` use it in your input type field

Comment: yes the error is removed now. but it is now showing destination in cart.index page ( same issue ) . white using dd($request) it show the value of array destination,